# Review "test question" is loaded

Tags: discussion, review

Recently during processing the review queue for "first posts" I was presented an answer for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464868/update-to-clamav-0-98-3) question for review

The answer was obviously poorly formed, at least in the explanation sense, however I felt that the answer had was potentially correct (user suggested installing libssl-dev for satisfying a build dependency with `./configure`) As I do not have edit privileges and neither do I have a system to reproduce/test the error I marked it as "No action needed" because there is no relevant flag for requesting an edit/review on a poorly written but otherwise valid attempt at an answer

I was informed that I "failed" the test for reviewing it as no action-needed even though I felt, fundamentally, that the answer contributed to solving the issue that OP had, and considering that there were no other answers to the question, a low quality attempt (that again, I considered valid) was better than what had been a few comments that led to nowhere, and that comments and community engagement would be better served than flagging for moderator attention

ANyway, I guess the point of this post is, what is the best way to handle answers that you consider to be good faith attempts, but may otherwise require a work to be considered "good" for a user that doesn't have privileges to otherwise edit/fix the post themselves

Comment: Appropriate flag/button is "Skip" ;-)